# Binary search tree lookup output

Tags: c, recursion, struct, binary-search-tree, function-definition

I am attempting to implement a lookup function for a binary search tree. While it does return true if I lookup the root of the tree, when I lookup other entries that are in the tree it returns false. When I debugged it the function seemed to return 1 but would then continue running and then return 0 at the end. It was my understanding that the function should terminate as soon as it returns any value so I'm not sure why this is happening.

```
int lookup(int n,struct node* x)
{
    if (x->data==n)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (x->left==NULL && x->right==NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (n>x->data && x->right!=NULL)
    {
        lookup(n,x->right);
    }
    else
    {
        lookup(n,x->left);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you do the recursive calls, what do you return then?

Comment: You probably want to write `return (lookup(n,x->right));` instead of just `lookup(n,x->right);`.

Comment: Sorry, @Stef . I didn't see your comment while typing. It turns out to be the same, I did not actually copy your input however.... Feel free to make your own explained answer and we can have a race for upvotes. ;-)

Comment: I think I've got it now. So the "return 1" was exiting out of the recursive call of lookup but since I wasn't returning that, the first call still reached "return 0"? Both very helpful thank you.

Comment: sb2346 Please wait a little for Stefs  possibly upcoming answer, before you decide on which one to accept. He deserves a little patience.

Comment: Hi @Yunnosch, no hard feelings, I do not plan on writing an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function has incorrect behavior because it returns nothing in these if statements

```
    else if (n>x->data && x->right!=NULL)
    {
        lookup(n,x->right);
    }
    else
    {
        lookup(n,x->left);
    }
```

That is the control will be passed to the last return statement after the if-else statements

```
    return 0;
```

But if you will update the function like

```
int lookup(int n,struct node* x)
{
    if (x->data==n)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (x->left==NULL && x->right==NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (n>x->data && x->right!=NULL)
    {
        return lookup(n,x->right);
    }
    else
    {
        return lookup(n,x->left);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

nevertheless the function can invoke undefined behavior because it does not check whether the pointer `x` is equal to `NULL`.

For example let's assume that `x->data` is not equal to `n` and `n` is less than `x->data`. Also let's assume that `x->left` is equal to `NULL` and `x->right` is not equal to `NULL`.

In this case the sub-statement of the first if statement

```
    if (x->data==n)
    {
        return 1;
    }
```

will not be executed.

And the sub-statement of the second if statement also will not be executed because `x->right` is not equal to `NULL`.

```
    else if (x->left==NULL && x->right==NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

The same problem will exists with the third if statement.

So the control will be passed inside the last else statement

```
    else
    {
        lookup(n,x->left);
    }
```

where the function is called with the null-pointer `x->left`. Thus in the second call of the function you will try to use the null-pointer to access memory

```
    if (x->data==n)
    {
        return 1;
    }
```

The function can be written the following way. Pay attention to that as the function does not change the tree itself its second parameter should be declared with the qualifier `const`.

```
int lookup( int n, const struct node *x )
{
    if ( x == NULL )
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if ( n < x->data )
    {
        return( n, x->left );
    }
    else if ( x->data < n )
    {
        return ( n, x->right );
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Also usually such a function is declared with the first parameter that specifies the pointer to the node (to the tree) and the second parameter specifies what is searched. That is like

```
int lookup( const struct node *x, int n );
```

Or even like

```
_Bool lookup( const struct node *x, int n );
```

Answer (score 4):

The value returned by your recursive `lookup` calls (i.e. `lookup(n,x->right);` and `lookup(n,x->left);`) is ignored, even if it is the correct one.
This is because at the end of the function (i.e. after returning from one of those calls) you unconditionally `return 0;`.

Replacing `lookup(n,x->XXX);` with `return lookup(n,x->XXX);` is what you want to do.

Comment: In case Stef also has an explained answer here upvote that one please.

Comment: I did already - and I like your way. If it still needs it feel free. Though I would prefer more of your proposals as comment.

Answer (score 1):

You do a recursive call but you do *not return* its result!

The simplest recursive version of your code would be:

```
int lookup(int n, struct node* x)
{
    if (x == NULL)
        return 0;

    if (n == x->data)
        return 1;

    if (n < x->data)
        return lookup(n, x->left);
    else
        return lookup(n, x->right);
}
```

As long as it didn't get out of the branch it tests the current node - when the value is found, 1 is returned, otherwise the lookup dives into a left or right branch. When the path ends (`x == NULL`) the value was not found, and 0 is returned.

The result propagates upwards on return from recursion.

The simplest iterative version:

```
int lookup(int n, struct node* x)
{
    while (x != NULL)
    {
        if (n == x->data)
            return 1;

        if (n < x->data)
            x = x->left;
        else
            x = x->right;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It works similarly to the recursive one except that it does not dive into recursion and just moves the `x` pointer down the tree. If the value is found prior the branch end, 1 is returned. Otherwise the result is 0 when scan walks past a tree leaf.